What can I use to fill misplaced bolt holes in concrete for redrilling?
Attempting DIY hand rail from concrete stoop to sidewalk. There are two vertical support rails each with a 4 hole base plate. The lower 4 holes came out perfect. The upper holes ended up being off. I need to fill the 3/8 x 2.5" holes and then re-drill. What would be the best patch product to accomplish this? Thanks

Welcome. Please take the [tour]. I've revised your title a bit to better meet our expectations.

How far off were the holes?  Anything less than 1/2 inch will be difficult to drill new strong enough holes to hold screws/bolts even with patching.

If the new holes overlap the existing holes drill the new holes first and use glue-in anchors. with the glue filling the now oversized holes.
This means you'll need a tube of 2 part concrete epoxy and some glue in anchor bolts, suitable nuts,  a caulking gun to operate the tube and something to blow the dust out of the holes (like a straw)

It depends how far off the holes are.  It may make more sense to fill the "wrong" holes with epoxy and redrill, rather than slathering epoxy on bolts.

slathering bolts? no the tube has a long nozzle to fill the hole with,  then you poke the bolt in and spin it a little to ensure a good bond. then tighten nuts on both sides of the base plate (or a base place template)  to hold the bolt in position while the epoxy cures.

Hydraulic cement patch is a common recommendation, but it may be difficult to get into the small holes. You might want to use something like epoxy. Be sure to clean the holes out well with compressed air or even water and a vacuum.
When you re-drill you're going to need a rigid guide to keep the bit from slipping into whichever is softer between the original concrete and the patch material. Maybe the rail plates will work. If the hole doesn't come out clean you may need to overdrill and use an expansion anchor of some sort.
